# Put a div on the bottom of a content which is in a container

Tags: css

I would like to put a div on the bottom of a subcontent which is itself in a container, 
sub-contents are dynamically generated.

Here is my html code

```
<div id="Content">
  <div class="subcontent"></div>
  <div class="subcontent"></div>
  <div class="subcontent"></div>
  <div class="pagenumber"></div>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
#content {
float: left;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 450px;
overflow: auto;
padding: 10px;
width: 978px;
}
.subcontent {
 float: right;
    height: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 700px;
}
DIV.pagenumber {
text-align: right;
 ???
}
```

[image: Here is a depicting of what I want to do]

Comment: DIV.pagenumber {
text-align: right;
clear:both;
}

Comment: Thank you ! Make an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Do you want it fixed to the bottom of the div or just ensure it doesn't take part in the floating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `clear:both`, this will clear any floats. http://jsfiddle.net/Kdt84/

```
DIV.pagenumber {
text-align: right;
clear:both;
}
```